# Monte Carlo simulation of amoeba population

Tags: python, montecarlo

I came across a brain teaser problem.  Im trying to simulate it, but having trouble getting the answer.  The problem goes like this: there is one amoeba.  every minute, an amoeba either may die, stay the same, split into 2 or split into 3 with equal probability.  All of its offspring will behave the same way, independent of other amoebas.  What is the probability that amoeba population will die?

My implementation in python:

```
import numpy as np


def simulate(n):
    prob = np.array([0.25]*4)
    ans = np.random.choice(np.arange(4),1,p=prob)

    if ans == 0:
        n = n - 1
    if ans == 1:
        pass
    if ans == 2:
        n = n * 2
    if ans == 3:
        n = n*3
    return n


count = 0
for i in range(10000):
    nold = 1
    while True:
        nnew = simulate(nold)
        if nnew == 0: #amoeba has died
            count += 1
            break;
        nold = nnew
```

Im getting an infinite loop.  Can anybody help?  thanks.  The answer is 41%

Answer (score 0):

The While loop needs to have some sort of breakpoint.

You have not set what is False.

```
while count < 10000:
    ...
```

Comment: There already is a break point. The current code just doesn't guarantee it will ever be reached. And this code is full of other conceptual mistakes anyway.

Comment: is the mistake in the simulate function or the for loop?